# Using Page Type without XPM

Tags: experience-manager

In our current setup (headless content delivery), we haven't implemented XPM.
From the CMS side, we enabled XPM and converted a page to "Page Type." Is there any possibility to create pages using "Page Type" pages in CMS?

I can use the the core service and read "Page Type" pages and simulate that behavior, before doing that I want to check any other options available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is something out of the box for this purpose. A page type is simply a page which is marked as 'page type', with an extra description and an example url. You could use it as a prototype to base new pages on (like XPM does), but you'd have to build this yourself.

As a starter, you could copy the 'page type' with the core service. Don't forget to clone the components on the page as well. And if these components contain links to other components, you may want to clone them too - or not, depending on your requirements.